# Adding filter for has_many relationship in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin as a reporting tool as well and leveraging the export to CSV feature to pull out specific data. This works fine, but I need to now filter results based on data being between 2 dates, but the dates are on on a model that is linked through a has_many relationship.

Here is an example

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  # has field: 'date'
end
```

I can load patients in RailsAdmin and in the list view show the appointments, but how can I add a filter to only show patients that have an appointment between Date X and Y? Is this possible at all?

Is there anyway to use named scope and pass in parameters? Or what about a virtual model for rails_admin to load? The SQL is pretty simple for this, but I'm just not sure how to pass in the actual date parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I am also curious as to how to solve this.

One option is to add appointments to filter dropdown but it will not allow you to choose dates.

```
rails_admin do
  include_all_fields
  field :appointments do
    filterable true
  end
  list do
    filters [:appointments] # this will make it show up by default
  end
end
```

Another choice is to create [custom action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action) and create page at app/views/rails_admin/mail/filter.html.haml where you can build regular search form